# DVD tray keeps popping out

Tags: linux-mint, dvd

Yesterday, I installed Linux Mint 17.3 Rosa. Currently I have WIndows 8.1 and Linux Mint 17.3 Rosa as my OS. When ever I use Linux, my DVD tray keeps popping out. Yet I have no problems while running Windows. How can I diagnose and fix this problem?

Comment: Are you unmounting your DVD device?

Comment: Nop. It keeps unmounting on its own.